# Styling issues with a input slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Trying to get my outputs to show up in line with the words explaining them, right now, they are being shunted to the next line, which I dont want.

```
Taco Stands:    Cost per <b><output class="output6">0</output></b> tacos<br>
TacoTaco <output class="output1">0</output>
Los Hermanos Tacos <output class="output2">0</output>
Natcho Taco<output class="output3">0</output>
Taco Bell<output class="output4">0</output>
Chipolte<output class="output5">0</output>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnpqd8cs/

I also cant seem to figure out how to have the output numbers have commas for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of    `output {
  display: block;
}`
Block will display the elements as the separate line. Either remove this or use    `output {
  display: inline;
}` :)

Comment: Doh! I was so concentrated on the js I completely forgot that line in the css!

Comment: Yeah! It happens! Please accept the answer if it worked! :)

Comment: It worked great! Any ideas on the second part of my question? how to have the output numbers have commas for better readability?

Comment: Seems my work is already done here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript Have a look!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap every line with output in a div and remove the `display: block;` from the outputs. You should have a block container for each row containing the text and the output to be separated like you want it.

```
<div>Taco Stands:    Cost per <b><output class="output6">0</output></b> tacos</div>
<div>TacoTaco <output class="output1">0</output></div>
<div>Los Hermanos Tacos <output class="output2">0</output></div>
<div>Natcho Taco<output class="output3">0</output></div>
<div>Taco Bell<output class="output4">0</output></div>
<div>Chipolte<output class="output5">0</output></div>
```